# Kivy: access app methods in a class from a different file

Tags: python, kivy

I have four different files which for example look like this (it is not a working code but the idea should be clear):

`main.py`:

```
from app import MyApp

def main():
    fmapp = MyApp()
    fmapp.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`app.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from SelectableLabel import SelectableLabel

class MyApp(App):
    def show_items(self):
        someList = ['1', 'someText']
        self.root.ids.someotherRecID.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in someList]
```

`SelectableLabel.py`:

```
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableRecipeLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableRecipeLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        global selection
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            selection = rv.data[index]['text']
            # MyApp().show_items() <-- How to call this to show items
```

part of `myapp.kv`:

```
....
....

RecycleView:
    id: recID
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(30)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'     
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False
....
....
```

Basically there is a RecycleView (`id: someotherRecID`) List which I want to update when an item is selected in another RecycleView (`id: recID`). I can do this easy when SelectableLabel class and MyApp class are in one file through global variables but how can I do the same in seperate files? Is there a good practice how to handle things I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks in advance!

This here for example works for me but I want to split it:

allinoneapp.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableRecipeLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableRecipeLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        global selection
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            selection = rv.data[index]['text']
            fmapp.show_items() # <-- accessing method through global app object

class MyApp(App):
    def show_items(self):
        someList = ['1', 'someText']
        self.root.ids.someotherRecID.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in someList]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fmapp = MyApp()
    fmapp.run()
```